# How do I access IdentityServer4 access and id tokens in .Net Framework to build a cookie

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

I've set up an IdentityServer4 project and have an existing ASP.NET Framework project that needs to authenticate users via the Identity Server. I can redirect and log in users, and redirect back, but at this point I need to build a cookie with information passed in from the id token and access token.

My question is really in 3 parts:

1) Where can I hook into .Net Framework to build a cookie from values I have retrieved from the identity server tokens?

2) I have read that it is not a good idea to put all your user claims in your id_token due to the size, so I need to request an access token after redirection I think - how is this achieved?

3) What is the role of GrantTypes and ResponseTypes and how does this work in respect to .Net Framework? Do they need to be set to a certain value for it to work with .Net Framework?

I've got my .Net Framework project set up near as makes no difference to the example from here:
https://nahidfa.com/posts/identityserver4-and-asp-.net-mvc/
So if answers could explain with this in mind I would really appreciate it!

Cheers

Comment: what do you mean by building a cookie? I use cookie auth in my post, what do you do that you need to make the cookie manually? feel free to post your code @josh

Comment: The flow that I want is: user signs in and is redirected to client with id token. Client accesses that id token and uses the claims inside to build a cookie for the user. Is this not the normal approach? The reason I want it this way is I already have an existing cookie in the server that is used extensively, so I would like to preserve that as much as possible. Unfortunately I cant post code as its not my intellectual property.

Comment: what you ask is handled by OIDC middleware.

Comment: Is there a way I can customize this or override it so I can at the very least rename the cookie that is created by the middleware?

Comment: Yes, the value set for `AuthenticationType` on `UseCookieAuthentication` is setting the cookie name, for example if we set it like  `AuthenticationType = "CustomCookies"` then cookie name would be `.AspNet.CustomCookies` - in this case just make sure to set `SignInAsAuthenticationType` to be `CustomCookies` on `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`